# Placeholder answers

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

I have noticed that this practice, which [is discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269993/placeholder-answers-will-update-with-answer-soon), has started to occur here.

I'd be interested to hear some of the moderators' takes on this.

Personally, I would hope that it does not take hold as—in addition to the reasons outlined in the meta post above—it just clutters the wiki with useless edits and, in emphasising speed over substance, undermines the commitment to quality that the community here has worked hard to establish.

I'm going to start flagging for deletion as "Not an answer".

Comment: I'll post a full answer when I get the chance, but in the meantime: yes, please flag. Answers should be more than placeholders when posted. Last thing we need here is the fastest gun in the west syndrome.

Comment: I'd noticed it as well. Flag them.

Comment: I always post a comment similar to @terdon and actually work on an answer, but even being disabled I agree that this practice should not be tolerated.

Comment: I can see how gaming the game this way might work for people sometimes on S.O., but we don't generally get people dropping nine identical answers in 3 minutes, so perhaps they will eventually clue in that doing this is just pointless here.

Comment: Posting a comment is much appreciated. Fast comments get the process moving. But posting a placeholder answer is just plain rude. Placeholder answers discourage other people from reading the posting, other people who might actually know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the good things about this site is that we tend to vote for long, comprehensive answers. The most voted answer is often not the first posted. With that in mind, placeholder answers are even sillier here than on larger sites like SO. Just take your time, write up a good answer and post it.

Apart from being unnecessary, it is also a bad habit to get into. Such answers are pointless and basically noise. If you see one, feel free to flag as "not an answer" and we'll deal with it.